# How do I format this date

Tags: android, kotlin, date, java-time, timezone-offset

I am trying to parse the date which is in the format `2021-01-15T19:00:00+0000`. I am not sure which format it is but based on my research I tried with methods below

```
1. val odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-01-15T19:00:00+0000")
2. val zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-01-15T19:00:00+0000")
```

It is logging the exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-01-15T19:00:00+0000' could not be parsed at index 19
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
        at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:591)
        at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:576)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
OffsetDateTime
.parse( 
    "2021-01-15T19:00:00+0000" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx" ) 
)
.toString()
```

> 2021-01-15T19:00Z

## `OffsetDateTime`

Your input has an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC, the `+0000` portion.

So you should be parsing with `OffsetDateTime` rather than `ZonedDateTime`.

### `ZonedDateTime`

The `ZonedDateTime` class is for a time zone rather than an offset. A time zone is the named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region, as decided by their politicians. Time zones have a name in format of `Continent/Region` such as `Europe/Paris` or `America/Edmonton`.

### Optional COLON in offset

Unfortunately, your input omitted the COLON character from between the hours and minutes of the offset. While optional in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, the `parse` method expects to find that character.

If you know all the inputs have the same `+0000` I would simply perform a string manipulation.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2021-01-15T19:00:00+0000".replace( "+0000" , "+00:00" ) ) ;
```

If some other offsets might appear, you must specify a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/0khePd).

> 2021-01-15T19:00Z

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the OffsetDateTime with the right offset - that should do the trick!

Comment: I agree with you that `OffsetDateTime ` is the right class to use. But the offset `+0000` *is* right. It’s allowed according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).